# Generate a graph with Excel from a table which has on a column the serie definition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I am struggling for a problem I have with Excel

I got output results from an instrument (a dynamometer) and I imported the values in Excel using PowerQuery. The three measurements were "a.xml", "b.xml", "c.xml".

I was able to get a big table which has on the first column the name of the measure (name of the series), and on column D "`encoder1`" the x-values of the graph and E column "`ch1`" the Y value of the graph.

I would like to make a single graph with three different series (a.xlm, b.xml, c.xml) overlapped. When creating the graph I tried placing on the `x`  the formula [Se means IF in Italia]:

```
=SE(Test[Source.Name]="a.xml";Test[encoder1])
```

and `y`

```
=SE(Test[Source.Name]="a.xml";Test[ch1])
```

but I get an error, "formulation not correctly imputed".

I send you the files through the link:

[Source and excel data](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/NJxUN7TP#link)

and a screenshot of the data table:

[image]

Does somebody know how can I obtain the desired graph automatically? In the future, I could have more than three measurements to be done.

Comment: Why is there a semi-colon in your formula? IF formulas take commas, not semi-colons. [See also here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2#:~:text=Use%20the%20IF%20function%2C%20one,another%20value%20if%20it's%20false.&text=For%20example%3A,B4%2DA4%2C%22%22)

Comment: syntax is: `=IF(test;[if_true];[if_false])`. It works if I write it on a cell. Can it be there are synthax differences between Italian and American/British version??

Comment: I confirm ... Italian version uses semi-colon. English one not.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. It just threw me off. :)